# Clear Only a Field After Postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I know that we can clear values of all fields by ModelState.Clear(). But what if I'd like to clear only a field, such  as incorrect security image code, and all the other fields will remain same.

Any helps will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValidField(key))
{
    var emptyValue = new ValueProviderResult(
        string.Empty,
        string.Empty,
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

    ModelState.SetModelValue(
        key,
        emptyValue);
}
```